# If N and M/N are free A modules on the ring A with 1, then M is also a free A module

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I would like to proove the following :

> If N and M/N are free A modules on the ring A with 1, then M is also a free A module.

My main issue is that we dont know if N and M/N have a finite rank. What i have tried so far:
I know that for every m $\in$ M there exists unique non zeros $a_1, a_2,...a_k \in A$ and $ n_1, n_2,....n_k \in N$ such that 
$m=a_1 n_1+...+a_k n)k$

Furthermore, since M/N is also free, i can write for any m' $\in$ M 
$m' =a_1 (m_1+N)...+a_k(m_k+M)$

I dont know how to get 'rid' of the $m_i+N$

any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Use the projectivity of free modules.  Note that you have an exact sequence $0\to N\to M\to M/N\to 0$.

Comment: What is the projectivity of free modules? @Batominovski

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is a short exact sequence of modules, and $C$ is free. Then the sequence must split, in particular $B\simeq A\oplus C$, proving that if $A,C$ are free, so is $B$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Show that $p\colon M\to M/N$ has a linear section, i.e. a homomorphism $s\colon M/N$ such that $p\circ s=\operatorname{id}_M$. Deduce that $M$ is isomorphic to the direct sum $N\oplus M/N$.

*Some details –* Indeed, let $(e_i),~1\le i\le r$ be a basis of $M/N$, and $m_i$ elements in $M$ such that $p(m_i)=e_i$. The $m_i$ are linearly independent  since their images mod. $N$ are. Hence they constitute a basis of a free submodule $N'\subset M$, and the restriction of $p$ to $N'$ is an isomorphism. The inverse isomorphism is  the linear map $$\begin{align*}s\colon M/N&\longrightarrow N'\\e_i&\longmapsto m_i,\end{align*}$$ 
which is a section of $p$ if you consider it as a map with codomain $M$, i.e. $p\circ s=\operatorname{id}_{M/N}$.

Now let $m\in M$. We have $m-s(p(m))\in N$, since $p(m-s(p(m)))=p(m)-p(s(p(m)))=p(m)-p(m)=0$.  Thus
$$m=(m-s(p(m)))+s(p(m))\in N+N'.$$
Since, if $n\in N$, $p(n)=0$, it is obvious that $N\cap N'=0$.

Comment: can you give me more details? im still confused

Comment: @J.M.: I've added some details. Hope it's clearer.